# Bash unexpected token near <<< here document

Tags: bash

My terminal's character encoding is set to `UTF-8`. I went into the terminal program's Profile Preferences / Compatibility and clicked `Reset Compatibility Options to Defaults`.

I ssh'd to another machine using this terminal window.

I ran `vi` and typed in the following script in *by hand* (to avoid any unexpected hidden special characters) on that machine. Then I ran it and got `syntax error near unexpected token <<<`

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$1"

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  printf 'cd fail'
  exit 1
fi

while read name
do
  printf 'item: [%s]\n' "$name"
done <<< "$(stat -t ./* | awk -F' ' '{print $13 " " $1}' | sort -r | awk -F' ' '{print $2}')"
```

This  test machine has `/bin/bash` ... also `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/bash`. `/bin/bash --version` says `GNU bash, version 2.05a.0(3)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`

I can disconnect from that test machine and in the same terminal window type the same script by hand on my machine and it runs fine. On my machine, `/bin/bash --version` says `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

What's causing the syntax error on the test machine? Is `<<<` not supported in that earlier version of Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure - that feature came in with 2.05**b** which git shows as July 2002, while 2.05**a** was November 2001.

bash's developer doesn't put dates in the changelog, but with some patience you can see the changes in [git CHANGES](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/CHANGES?id=7117c2d221b2aed4ede8600f6a36b7c1454b4f55)